# What is the best way to aggreatate and also access specific data within a few tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been struggling with Postgres queries and I think the high level problem I'm struggling with is the best way to structure aggregation and non-aggregation within the same query.

For example, say I have a list of companies. I want to take IBM's revenue and divide it against the sum of its industry's entire revenue. Those kind of queries are causing me to build complex logic that I'm not sure if it's the best approach.

For example, if I have this query:

```
select extract(year from fisy.date), 
(c.carbon/ln(fisy.totalrevenue- fisy.grossprofit)) as emissionsPerCOGS
from company."financials_Income_Statement_yearly" fisy 
join company.carbon c 
on lower(c.ticker) = lower(fisy.ticker)
where lower(fisy.ticker) = 'ibm.us'
```

This works fine, it gives me year and a formula result for each year.

But say I have another table general and in general I have details on ibm, and I want to see IBM's results above aligned to their industry. I can get the list of tickers, for the where statement via:

```
select lower(g4.ticker)
from "company"."General" g4
where industry = (
        select industry
        from "company"."General" g3
        where lower(g3.ticker) = 'ibm.us'
    )
```

But at this point, I'm confused If I included this in the where statement then all the select results are for the aggregated data and I get confused by having to select/filtering IBM's data specifically out of it.

So my question is, is there a straightforward way to get aggregated data and individual (ibm type) data so I can take individual sets of data in my DB and compare it against some aggregated view?

Comment: I'm lost.  What do your tables look like?  Your queries reference three different tables and it is not clear what is what.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm not sure how to get that info, should I be adding schema? I think my question was more generally than the first query works but I want to aggregate it to compare IBM against it's industry. I have the query to get it's industry but then I cannot access IBM's individual data because it's all aggregated.

Comment: . . Some (simplified) sample data for all the tables mentioned in the query is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For example, say I have a list of companies. I want to take IBM's revenue and divide it against the sum of its industry's entire revenue.

This problem statement is pretty simple.  I don't know what the *queries* in your question have to do with this problem.  But you could just do:

```
select sum(revenue) filter (where company = 'IBM') / sum(revenue)
from t;
```

You can add a `where` clause if you want to limit this to a particular set of companies.

Or, if you wanted this for all companies:

```
select company, sum(revenue), sum(sum(revenue)) over ()
from t
group by company;
```

Comment: ok I understand why it's complicated without the data. I tried your approach it kind of works. but it shows the same result for each year.  If I do something like this : select sum(revenue) filter (where company = 'IBM') / sum(revenue) - can I somehow also ensure the years it's pulling from are aligned to the years in the overall query?

Comment: @Lostsoul . . . Just add a `where` clause for the years you want.